# redirect page but keep meta tags

Tags: php, html, redirect, seo, meta-tags

Im redirecting a page using

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Google indexed my page but is using the meta tag of the page im redirecting to.
Is there a way to keep my meta tags for google but still redirect to the site?
Maybe with a countdown before redirect?

greets

Answer (score 0):

You could use this instead.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

The 0 after content can be replaced with a number of seconds before the page is redirected. [Here's](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204645160/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-meta-tag) some more information. 
 Alternatively, you could use robots.txt, or redirect using javascript. For robots.txt, follow this guide. http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html
 *Let me know if this helped you out!*

Comment: are you sure my meta tags will be used with this? is it important to set a timer higher than 0 or does 0 work too?

Comment: I'm not sure. If you leave it at zero, it will redirect immediately. If you give it a delay, you can display a message to the user to let them know they are about to be redirected. Check out the link I added about robots.txt.

Comment: i figured out that if you use content="0" it will be treated as 301 but with content higher than 0 it will be a 302 what is exactly what i needed, thanks